# Basic vs. compound condition coverage

Tags: testing, code-coverage, test-coverage

I'm trying to get my head around the differences between these 2 coverage criteria and I can't work out how they differ. I think I'm failing to understand exactly what decision coverage is. My software testing textbook states that compound decision coverage can be costly (2<sup>n</sup> combinations for n basic conditions).

I would have thought basic condition coverage would be costlier.

Consider `a && b && c && d && e`. My understanding is that in basic condition coverage, each of these atomic variables have to have the value TRUE and FALSE in a test case for the test case to be have basic condition adequacy - that's 32 different test cases.

So what is the actual difference, and what is referred to as a "basic condition". In the example above, is `a` a basic condition?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Regarding terminology, I don't have a single source handy that uses the exact terms "basic condition coverage" and "multiple condition coverage". Binder's "Testing Object-Oriented Systems" says "condition coverage" and "multiple-condition coverage". Everett & McLeod's "Software Testing" says "simple condition coverage" and "compound condition coverage". But I'm certain that the first term in each case is your "basic condition coverage" and the second is your "compound condition coverage". I'll use those terms below.

**Basic condition coverage** means that every basic condition in the program is true in some test and false in some test, regardless of other conditions. In the following

```
if a && b && c
  # do stuff
else
  # do other stuff
end
```

there is a compound condition, `a && b && c`, with three basic conditions, `a`, `b` and `c`. It takes only two test cases, one where all basic conditions are true and one where all are false, to get full basic condition coverage. It doesn't matter that the basic conditions happen to be part of a compound condition.

Note that basic condition coverage is not branch coverage. If the compound condition were `a && b && !c`, those two test cases above would still achieve basic condition coverage but would not achieve branch coverage.

A less aggressively optimized set of test cases for basic condition coverage would have one test case where all three basic conditions are false and three test cases with a different basic condition true in each. That would still only be four of the eight possible combinations of basic conditions in the compound condition. The uncomfortable feeling that we're ignoring the other four is why there's **compound condition coverage**. That requires a test for each possible combination of basic conditions in a compound condition. In the example above, you'd need eight tests, one for each possible combination of possible values of `a`, `b` and `c`, to get full compound condition coverage.

Comment: Now I'm really confused because unless I've misinterpreted, your solution to "basic condition coverage" is different from the one stated by @GeraldMucke, where you would create a truth table and write all combinations of the possible truth values, giving is 2^3 = 8 test cases.

Comment: Not what I intended to convey. Basic = each condition must be true in one test and false in another, independent of other conditions. Compound = there must be a test for all combinations of basic conditions in a compound condition. I'll try to edit to make that clearer.

Comment: Okay, understood, but does this still not differ from the definition stated by the other user?

Comment: It does. I'll comment on that answer.

Comment: Right. I'm confused because by reading the definition in Pezze and Young's book, the other answers definition seems more correct. Could you possibly provide more insight with respect to the definition in the book? Thanks :)

Comment: I think I understand it now. I've been thinking of relating the test cases to a truth table. But all we want is for each atomic variable to have an instance of true AND false in all the test cases. So for example, given `a && b && c`, then the following 2 test cases would provide basic condition coverage: `T, F, T; F, T,F` because `a` has both true and false values, as does `b` and `c` - as do the instantiations in your original post. Is this a correct understanding?

Comment: Yes, that's it exactly.

Comment: Okay thanks for the help. I will select your answer as accepted,

Comment: On another note, in the same book and again on chapter 12.4, when discussing compound condition coverage, for the expression `a && b && c && d && e`, they only use 6 test cases, and not 2^5 = 32 test cases as expected. They mention "short circuit Boolean operators" without explaining what this is. Do you know what's going on here?

Comment: That would be a good question on its own, but, briefly, it's because if the left side of `&&` is false the right side isn't evaluated, so not all combinations are possible.

Comment: Ah right, it's like some programming languages that use early termination when checking decisions. That makes sense.

Comment: I'd like to add to this if possible. What if we have a nested condition. For example. `if (x) { if (y) { ... } }`. Say `x` is false, then `if (y)` won't be triggered, would that be classified as a false in condition testing, or simply classified as nothing, so we still need a test case that explicitly makes it `true` and `false`?

Comment: It's nothing. You need two test cases with x true, one with y true and one with it false.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. It was kind of an obvious question but I've been studying for 10 exams for so long that my brain is now mush...

Answer (score 2):

First, the difference between *Decision* and *Condition*.

A *Condition* is an atomar boolean expression that can not be broken down into simpler boolean expression. For example: `a` (if `a` is boolean).

A *Decision* is a compound of Conditions with zero or more Boolean operators. A Decision without an operator is also a condition. For example: `(a or b) and c` but also `a and b` or just `a`.

Lets take a simple example

```
if(decision)  {
  //branch 1
} else {
  //branch 2
}
```

You need two tests to cover both branches. Thats the *decision coverage* or *branch coverage*. In case the decision is a condition (i.e. just `a`), that is also called *basic condition coverage*, which is the coverage of the two branches of a single condition.

The `decision` can be broken down into conditions.

Lets take for example

```
decision = (a or b) and c
```

The *decision coverage* would be achieved with

- a,b,c = 0
- a,b,c = 1

But the permutation of all the combinations of its boolean sub expressions is the *full condition coverage* or *multiple condition coverage*), which is the compound of the *basic condition coverage* :

```
| a | b | c |
| 0 | 0 | 1 |
| 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 0 | 1 | 1 |
| 0 | 1 | 0 |
| 1 | 0 | 1 |
| 1 | 0 | 0 |
| 1 | 1 | 1 |
| 1 | 1 | 0 |
```

That would be quite a lot of tests, but some of those are redundant as some conditions are covered by others. This is reflected in the *Modified Condition/Decision Coverage* (MC/DC) which is a combination of *condition coverage* and *function coverage*.

For MC/DC it is required, that each condition has to affect the outcome independently. With the above test (all are 0 or all are 1), we ignore the fact, that c-value doesn't matter if a and b are 0, or, that b-value doesnt matter if a and c are 1.

So you should sit down, use your brain, and think about for which combinations the overall result R is 1 or 0.

```
  | a | b | c | a or b | c | R |  eq
1 | 0 | 0 | 0 |    0   | 0 | 0 |  A
2 | 0 | 0 | 1 |    0   | 1 | 0 |  B
3 | 0 | 1 | 0 |    1   | 0 | 0 |  A
4 | 0 | 1 | 1 |    1   | 1 | 1 |  C
5 | 1 | 0 | 0 |    1   | 0 | 0 |  A
6 | 1 | 0 | 1 |    1   | 1 | 1 |  D
7 | 1 | 1 | 0 |    1   | 0 | 0 |  A
8 | 1 | 1 | 1 |    1   | 1 | 1 |  D
```

The last column shows the equivalence class:

- A: c = 0, result is 0, neither a nor b have an influence
- B: a,b = 0, result is 0, c has no influence
- C: b,c = 1, result is 1, a has no influence
- D: a,c = 1, result is 1, b has no influence

For B and C it's quite obvious which to pick, not so for A and D. For each you have to check, what would happen, if I replace the operators, i.e. or -> and, and -> or, how will this affect the result of the (sub)decision. If the result will be affected, you got a candidate - If not, you don't.

- A : (0 and/or 0) and/or 0 -> doesn't matter
- A : (0 and 1) vs (0 or 1) -> does matter! -> Candidate
- A : (1 and 0) vs (1 or 0) -> does matter! -> Candidate
- A : (1 and/or 1) -> doesn't matter
- D : (1 and 0) vs (1 or 0) -> does matter -> Candidate
- D : (1 and 1) -> doesn't matter

So you get the final test set as mentioned above:

- a = 0, b = 1, c = 0 -> false branch (A) OR a = 1, b = 0, c = 0
- a = 0, b = 0, c = 1 -> false branch (B)
- a = 0, b = 1, c = 1 -> true branch (C)
- a = 1, b = 0, c = 1 -> true branch (D)

Especially the latter test - changing the operators - can be done with tools like mutation testing, that do not just replaing operators, but can do quite some more, i.e. flipping operands, removing statements, change order of execution, replace return values etc. And for each alteration of your code, it verifies if the test actually fails. This is good indicator of the quality of your test suite and ensures that code is not just covered but your tests for the code are actually valid.

Regarding the terminology, I couldn't find the term "Compound Decision Coverage" somewhere. In my view a "compound decision" would be a compound of compounds of conditions, in other words: a compound of conditions.

Comment: Thanks alot for the reply. I agree with you that the term "Compound Decision Coverage" term can't be found - I've tried googling the term. FWIW, it occurs in the book "Software Testing and Analysis" by Mauro Pezzé and Michael Young. If you'd like to take a look, here are the slides for the corresponding chapter regarding compound condition coverage: https://ix.cs.uoregon.edu/~michal/book/slides/pdf/PezzeYoung-Ch12-Structural.pdf from slide 16 onwards.

Comment: "Basic condition coverage" isn't the same as "multiple condition coverage". You can see [Pezzè and Young](http://www.amazon.com/Software-Testing-Analysis-Principles-Techniques/dp/0471455938)'s definition by searching for "basic condition coverage" inside Amazon's copy of the book. You'll see it in section 12.4, "Condition Testing".

Comment: @Dave, yes you're right, the definitions are somewhat misleading, BCC is coverage of every branch of a single condition, i.e. a -> {true, false}, while MCC is the compound, ie. the permutation of all BCCs in that compound

Comment: Part of the reason why basic condition coverage is hard to understand is because it's not intuitively a good level of coverage. It doesn't guarantee branch or even statement coverage.