# Is there a good code coverage tool for basic branch coverage?

Tags: .net, code-coverage, opencover

[Basic vs. compound condition coverage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37122947/basic-vs-compound-condition-coverage/37123516#37123516)

I've been trying OpenCover, but its default branch coverage is compound condition coverage. The trouble with this is that while it's exact, it's far less useful than basic coverage.

I'd like to know if there's a way to make it give me the output in terms of basic branch coverage, or if there's another tool that can do this.

Comment: Asking for tools is off-topic on Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 0):

See Semantic Designs (my company's) family of [Test Coverage Tools](http://www.semanticdesigns.com/Products/TestCoverage/).

There is one member of the family for each language/dialect, including various versions of C#.